# Unable to read project 'Runner.xcodeproj'

Tags: flutter, xcode

Whenever I tried to run the flutter code in vs it shows the error like this

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Exception: Unable to get Xcode project information:
 2023-03-24 10:21:46.452 xcodebuild[2378:22866] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.}
2023-03-24 10:21:46.462 xcodebuild[2378:22866] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/w1/3p9t31q51k5c3dtmzsr5n7d00000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-24-03_15-51-0046.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'Runner.xcodeproj'.
    Reason: The project ‘Runner’ is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error. Examine the project file for invalid edits or unresolved source control conflicts.

Path: /Users/tapabratthakuria/Documents/FlutterDev/Flutter_app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
Exited
```

I tried to delete the whole code and after that again put and run.
Try fluter clean, and then reinstall flutter also but again shows the same problem.

Comment: Do you use ```git```?